# live update kml files geoxml

Tags: google-maps, parsing, kml, geoxml3

i'm trying to update kml files on the fly as described by google here:

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates?csw=1

my problem is: in my source code i triggered the update-load.kml after a short timeout

```
function initialize() {
          ...some code...

      myParser.parse('./point-load.kml');
      //so far everything is working fine, and the markers show up on the map
      window.setTimeout("Update()", 5000);
}

function Update() {
      myParser.parse('./update-load.kml');
}
```

after the update nothing happenes, no markers changed or moved, nothing...

the structure of my .kml files is exactly the same like in the link above

edit:

parsers added to function Update()

```
        function Update() {
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(28.019440, -17.382813); //set map center
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 3, //set default zoom level
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //set default map type(ROADMAP,SATELLITE,HYBRID,TERRAIN)
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); //***ORIGINAL***
            var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});


            myParser.parse('./update-load.kml');
        }
```

now: all markers dissapear

Comment: The kml is probably being cached by the browser.  Are the [Cache-Control Headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) set to prevent caching?  It would probably be best if you don't overwrite the parser on every read, use the same parser, just re-parse the same URL.  FYI - not a lot of testing was done on this functionality as it requires KML that modifies the position of the markers, which I don't have access to.

Comment: If the URL passed into parse is the same, it should re-parse the file and re-render it.  If the URLs are not the same it will overlay additional markers, unless you hide the first set before parsing the new URL.

Comment: [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_update.html?lat=37.430783&lng=-122.085125&zoom=10&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/dynamicmarkerkml.php)

Comment: Actually I had never seen [this page on incrementally updating data](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates) before.  Not sure if all that is built into [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or not; never been tested by me, but the original developer implemented network links, so it might just work, or if it doesn't, it might be easy to fix or implement.  Do you have KML files for your use case that can be used to test it?

Comment: Have you tried it on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) or in the API using KmlLayer?  It looks like it is "partially supported": `<NetworkLinkControl> | partially | <Update> and <expires> partially supported (see Notes section above)` from the [KML documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps)